# Javascript - Multidimensional Array Sorting - String And Int - Order By Int

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

After dragging divs in my javascript application... I want to assign a numeric class to all divs, ordered by the position. I've researched a lot, and builded the next... but it just does not work. (Inner HTML does not change)

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var i = 0;
var MyDrags = [];

while(ele[i]) {
    if(ele[i].id.substr(0, 4)=="drag") {
        MyDrags["distance"]=parseInt(document.getElementById(ele[i].id).style.top,10);
        MyDrags["id"]=ele[i].id;
    }
    i++;
}
MyDrags.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
});
i = 0;
while(MyDrags["distance"][i]) {
    document.getElementById(MyDrags["id"][i]).innerHTML=MyDrags["distance"][i];
    i++;
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend if you're going to do DOM manipulation to use Jquery or some other library. It can get hairy if you're doing anything complicated.

Comment: Use `MyDrags = []` instead of `MyDrags = new Array()` - it's cleaner and [more performant](http://jsperf.com/literal-vs-constructor-array/4).

Comment: @ChrisFrancis Thank you, I tested it twice... and `new Array()` is always the fastest. However, I will change my way of creating Arrays :)

Comment: @VoronoiPotato In this case it is just a Simple Y Axis drag and drop. Jquery is too complete for the simple thing I want :)

Comment: Really? Be careful with those results - it's laid out badly (1 - 3 are comparable, and 4 - 6 are comparable). The [original version](http://jsperf.com/literal-vs-constructor-array) is a better test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are overwriting the previous values, you need to assign a new object in each iteration, to have your code working, it should look like this:

```
var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
var i = 0;
var MyDrags = [], dst;

while (ele[i]) {
    if (ele[i].id.substr(0, 4) === 'drag') {
        MyDrags.push({
            distance: parseInt(document.getElementById(ele[i].id).style.top, 10),
            id: ele[i].id
        });
    }
    i++;
}

MyDrags.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.distance - b.distance;
});

i = 0; 
while(MyDrags[i]) {
    if (dst = MyDrags[i]['distance']) {
        document.getElementById(MyDrags[i]['id']).style.top = dst + 'px';
        document.getElementById(MyDrags[i++]['id']).innerHTML = dst;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you :D But when I try your code, the browser crashes after dragging the divs (when the sort code is called)... and it does nothing. What does the "dst" mean, when creating the array?

Comment: @Kenedy, i just pointed out the syntax/usage mistakes, i have no context of the rest of your page, would you mind posting a complete jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes, of course... thank you! :D I pasted the code from my original HTML, but it does not work in the fiddle. Anyway, this is the original FULL code. URL: http://jsfiddle.net/S7yVC/

Comment: Thank you again. Now, the problem is that it still does not show the sorted position. InnerHTML is never updated. If I put an alert in the last while it is never called... and if I put it before the while `alert(MyDrags["distance"]);` it outputs "Undefined"... strange...

Comment: Wow... it works perfectly!... What does the console log do in this case?

Comment: I'm glad, nothing, just debugging code i forgot to take out :)